# ¿Cómo puedo añadir atributos a un XML generado con zeep para hacer una llamada a una API SOAP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, zeep

Estoy generando un XML con la librería ZEEP para una API SOAP.

Mi problema es que según la documentación necesito añadir

```
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

en la etiqueta SOAP-ENV porque si no me da error al hacer la llamada.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo añadirle estos atributos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es mucho más complicado de lo que debería. Tras darle vueltas un buen rato he llegado a la siguiente solución, que no es del todo satisfactoria pero espero te sirva.

El problema es que, a menos que quieras manipular directamente la representación string del XML (cosa que no creo recomendable), lo que tenemos es la API de `lxml` para modificar los elementos del árbol XML. Y usando esa API no se pueden añadir atributos a un elemento cuyo nombre de atributo contenga dos puntos, porque esa sintaxis está reservada para los espacios de nombres *namespaces*.

En realidad, los atributos que necesitas añadir están definiendo dos nuevos *namespaces*, el primero llamado `tem` y el segundo llamado `xsi`. Se supone que más adelante tu documento usará esos prefijos como parte de otros atributos o elementos, con cosas como `xsi:type` por ejemplo, etc.

Por tanto parece que lo que debemos hacer es usar `lxml` para añadir dos nuevos *namespaces* al elemento raiz. Pero `lxml` no lo pone fácil, ya que:

1. Por un lado sólo añade *namespaces* si efectivamente los estás usando en algún otro atributo o hijo del elemento. Eso me obliga a crear un par de atributos "falsos" que usen esos namespaces. Por ejemplo, `tem:nil` y `xmlns:nil`, por poner algo. No tengo muy claro si esos nombres de atributo son válidos dentro de esos *namespaces*, por eso digo que espero que no te de problemas. Además tengo que darles un valor a esos atributos. Puesto que no son más que un "truco" para forzar a `lxml` para incluirlos, no sé qué valor darles y he optado por la cadena vacía.
2. `lxml` en principio decide por sí mismo qué prefijos usar para los *namespaces* que vayas añadiendo, en base a la URL a la que apuntan. En tu caso, la url `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` es "bien conocida" por `lxml` y le asigna el prefijo `xsi`, que coincide con lo que necesitas. En cambio la url `http://tempuri.org/` no le es conocida y le asigna como prefijo `ns0`, en lugar de `tem` que es lo que necesitas. Para cambiar eso hay que registrar esa url como un nuevo *namespace*, usando `etree.register_namespace()`.

Todo esto lo ejemplifica el siguiente código:

```py
from lxml import etree

# Registramos el nuevo namespace "tem"
etree.register_namespace('tem', 'http://tempuri.org/')

# Cargamos un documento de ejemplo
with open("ejemplo.xml") as f:
   d = etree.parse(f)

# En el documento cargado el elemento raiz era asi:
# <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

# Extraemos el raiz de ese documento
r = d.getroot()

# Añadimos un par de atributos nuevos al elemento raiz
# el primero que use el namespace tem y el segundo que use el namespace xsi
# Observa la sintaxis, que no usa directamente esos prefijos sino que 
# pone entre llaves la URL en cuestión
r.set("{http://tempuri.org/}nil", "")
r.set("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil", "")

# Al convertir de nuevo a su representación como cadena el documento...
print(etree.tostring(d))
# ...vemos que ahora el elemento raíz es volcado como:
# <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
#   xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
#   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
#   tem:nil="" xsi:nil="">
```

Como ves, el resultado es casi lo que necesitas, excepto que le sobran los atributos `tem:nil` y `xsi:nil`, pero espero que esos no te causen problema.

Todo esto (salvo cargar el fichero de ejemplo, ya que en tu caso el documento te llega como parámetro) tendrías que hacerlo dentro del método `egress` del plugin Zeep, del cual tienes un ejemplo [aqui](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html)

Comment: he imprimido por consola y he encontrado esto: 
Prefixes:
     ns0: http://tempuri.org/
     ns1: http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/
     xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Global elements:
     ns0:ActualizarEnvioAgregarUnidades(documento: {_value_1: ANY})
     ns0:ActualizarEnvioAgregarUnidadesResponse(ActualizarEnvioAgregarUnidadesResult: xsd:boolean)
     ns0:ActualizarSertEnvio(documento: {_value_1: ANY}) Parece ser que el registro ya está guardado pero está mal, supongo que solo tendria que modificarlo. Sabes si hay alguna forma de poder mofidicar el registro?

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir. ¿Cómo has imprimido eso por consola? ¿Desde python? ¿Desde el servidor? En caso de que sea desde python, qué has impreso exactamente? ¿Desde qué función? ¿Con qué instrucciones? Tampoco entiendo a qué te refieres con modificar el registro. ¿Dentro de una base de datos? ¿En el XML antes de enviarlo?

Comment: en la documentación de zeep te dice que puedes usar este comando en consola: python -m zeep http://www.soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl y eso te imprimirá todos la información del servicio. Al hacerlo he obtenido esa información. existe una variable (o entiendo que es una variable) llamada prefix y eso devuelve: ns0: http://tempuri.org/
     ns1: http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/
     xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Comment: Es muy difícil tratar de depurar (o entender) cuál es exactamente tu problema, sin tener todo tu "setup" para poder hacer yo mis pruebas. Si  yo desde línea de comandos hago `python -m zeep http://www.soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl` obtengo una información muy diferente a lo que dices, pero claro, eso es porque yo estoy tomando el `wsdl` de internet y tú pareces tener una copia local completamente distinta. Por otro lado, tampoco sé qué espera tu servidor porque en tu pregunta preguntabas por un par de prefijos concretos (`tem` y `xsi`) pero ahora aparecen otros (`ns0`, `ns1`)...

Comment: No puedo enviartelo porque el wsdl me lo ofrece una empresa privada. Pero he conseguido solucionar el problema de los prefijos. Te paso el código y responderé la pregunta para que quede constancia.          wsdl = 'WSDL'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
client.set_ns_prefix('tem', 'http://tempuri.org/')
client.set_ns_prefix('xsi',"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

Answer (score 2):

He conseguido encontrar la manera de añadir prefijos propios de forma manual, en este caso porque estaba obteniendo mal los prefijos que estaban en el wsdl.

Con la librería ZEEP cargamos el wsdl en un objeto. Este objeto tiene la función "set_ns_prefix", el cual necesita 2 valores, el prefijo y la url. Una vez cargados podemos imprimir los prefijos usando la variable "prefix" de dicho objeto.

```
import zeep

wsdl = 'archivo WSDL'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
client.set_ns_prefix('tem', 'http://tempuri.org/')
client.set_ns_prefix('xsi',"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
```